# HTML CSS :hover only border color not changing and only effects inner elements?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So I'm making some download links for my website. But when i hover over the elements inside, the border-color of the div doesnt change. And the only time anything changes is when i hover over the elements inside the div. So how can i make it so the border-color does change and so it detects whether I'm hovering over the div not the elements inside it

```css
div.db {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

.db :hover {
    border-color: red;
}
div.db :not(:hover){
    border-color: blue;
}

div.db img {
    width: 220px;
    height: 180px;
}

div.db a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h3>Downloads:</h3>
<div class="downloads">
  <div class="db">
    <a href="null">
      <img src="wld.png" />
      <p>Windows</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="db">
    <a href="null">
      <img src="lld.jpg">
      <p>Linux</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="db">
    <a href="null">
      <img src="ald.jpg">
      <p>Apple</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

the downloads div class doesnt have any code for it.

Comment: i believe it just a typo. here =======.db :hover========= it should be like this .db:hover

Comment: `div.db:not(:hover)` can be simplified to `.db`. Also either *remove* `div` from all selectors, or *add* them to all selectors, otherwise you operate on different **specificity**.

Comment: Your CSS doesn't have anything that would cause hovering any of the inner elements to change anything. Also, like @connexo said, you should be consistent with your selectors. Either make them all div.db, or all .db, otherwise you run into specificity issues.

Comment: And just to be clear, do you want the div's border color to change when either the div itself or any of its contents is hovered, or only when the div is hovered, or only when the contents are hovered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Wrong syntax** caused by **extra spaces**.

Using `.db: hover` is **incorrect**, change it to `.db:hover`

and so on...

```css
div.db {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

.db:hover {
    border-color: red;
}
div.db:not(:hover){
    border-color: blue;
}

div.db img {
    width: 220px;
    height: 180px;
}

div.db a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<h3>Downloads:</h3>
        <div class="downloads">
            <div class="db">
                <a href="null">
                    <img src="wld.png" />
                    <p>Windows</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="db">
                <a href="null">
                    <img src="lld.jpg">
                    <p>Linux</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="db">
                <a href="null">
                    <img src="ald.jpg">
                    <p>Apple</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: `div.db:not(:hover)` can be simplified to `.db`. Also either *remove* `div` from all selectors, or *add* them to all selectors, otherwise you operate on different **specificity**.

Comment: Thank you and much appreciated @connexo